# iOS BTLE background mode disconnections

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

My iOS device runs a central role and we have developed a device that runs a peripheral role.

I have include bluetooth-central background mode in the Info.plist. Background mode is working. Each 2 minutes iOS device gets notifications as expected. But usually after about 10 minutes, other times about 20 minutes the peripheral disconnects. I see the following in the log:

```
BTServer[67] <Error>: Core       Connection timed out to device "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
BTLEServer[203] <Notice>: (Note ) Peripheral "MyPeripheral" is now disconnected: Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=6 "The connection has timed out unexpectedly." UserInfo=0x16553040 {NSLocalizedDescription=The connection has timed out unexpectedly.}
BTLEServer[203] <Notice>: (Note ) Connecting peripheral "PeripheralName"...
```

After this, all connection progress starts, but I would like to avoid these periodic disconnections. Not sure if it is situation is caused by the app, iOS or the peripheral.

Comment: What is the chipset of your peripheral?

Comment: @GillesGregoire. We use nRF51822.

Comment: According to this link https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/5757/remoteuserterminatedconnection-reason-causes-disconnection-between-central-and-peripheral/ , the connection interval of this chip is critical to maintaining a connection. What is your connection interval?

Comment: @GillesGregoire. It seems it's a peripheral issue.

Comment: Assume you are using the new State Preservation and Restoration tools available since iOS 7: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1

Comment: @NickT. Restoration and state preservation is implemented. But is not called when this issue happens, although the peripheral reconnects. Restoration is called for example when I simulate Memory Eviction: kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);. Manager is restored then. The point is that I would like to avoid the disconnections.

Comment: Maria, could it be something to do with the Security Manager? See my recent answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920002/connection-problems-when-using-iphone-as-peripheral/27211522#27211522